# How do I print out each random result of the coin toss and how to print the best streak of a certain side? (Python)

Tags: python

I have to create a program that will simulate a coin toss. The user will be able to input how many times the coin will be tossed. The program will then randomly 'toss' it and print out Result 1: tails, Result 2: heads etc up to the input value. I also need to print at the end the highest streak for both tails and heads. However I am struggling with the code for both of these. I have the code for the random coin toss though.

```
import random

heads = 0
tails = 0
toss = heads + tails

toss = int(input("How many coin tosses would you like to simulate?"))

while heads + tails < toss:
    coin = random.randint(1, 2)
    if coin == 1:
        toss += 1
        heads = heads + 1
    else:
        coin == 2
        toss += 1
        tails = tails + 1
print("The total amount of heads: ",heads)
print("the best streak of heads: ",)
print("The total amount of tails: ",tails)
print("The best streak of tails: ",)
```

If anyone could help me out that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you are trying to achieve in the following way -

### Correct Solution -

```
import random

heads = 0
tails = 0
toss = heads + tails

toss = int(input("How many coin tosses would you like to simulate?"))
max_head_streak,max_tail_streak,curr_head_streak,curr_tail_streak=0,0,0,0
while heads + tails < toss:
    coin = random.randint(1, 2)
    if coin == 1:
        # If coin is 1, we increase count of head
        heads = heads + 1

        # Since the current one is head, we just increase current head streak and reset the tail streak
        curr_head_streak += 1
        curr_tail_streak = 0

    else:
        # if coin isn't 1, we increase count of tail
        tails = tails + 1

        # Similarly, We just increase current tail streak and reset head streak in this case
        curr_tail_streak += 1
        curr_head_streak = 0
    
    # On each iteration, we set the max_head_streak and max_tail_streak as per below -
    max_head_streak=max(max_head_streak,curr_head_streak)
    max_tail_streak=max(max_tail_streak,curr_tail_streak)

print("The total amount of heads: ",heads)
print("The best streak of heads: ",max_head_streak)
print("The total amount of tails: ",tails)
print("The best streak of tails: ",max_tail_streak)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
How many coin tosses would you like to simulate?10
The total amount of heads:  6
The best streak of heads:  3
The total amount of tails:  4
The best streak of tails:  2
```

**Where you went wrong -**

> #### Your code -
>
> ```
> while heads + tails < toss:
>     coin = random.randint(1, 2)
>     if coin == 1:
>         toss += 1
>         heads = heads + 1
>     else:
>         coin == 2
>         toss += 1
>         tails = tails + 1
> ```

Your code will run into an infinite loop since the loop will never break out of the loop. You are increasing the toss count as well as the head/tail count. You will only need to increase the head/tail count and not the toss count. Other changes can be made as per my solution above.

Comment: Do you know how have it print the result of the toss with result 1, result 2, result 3 etc? I cant get the numbers to accumulate on the result part so it just says result 1 for all of them

Comment: you can put the print statement in the while loop itself. Along with that keep an count variable and so you can do like this - `print('result '+str(count)+' '+str(coin))`. Put this statement right after coin

Comment: I am wondering why there is `toss = heads + tails` and then on the next row `toss = int(input("How many coin tosses would you like to simulate?"))`

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use dictionary (no defenses against user entering value what is not convertible to int):

```
import random


tries = input('How many coin tosses you like to simulate: ')
tosses = (random.choice(['head', 'tail']) for i in range(int(tries)))
 
results = {'heads': {'total': 0, 'best': 0, 'current': 0},
          'tails': {'total': 0, 'best': 0, 'current': 0}
          }
 
# alternative: {key: dict.fromkeys('total best current'.split(), 0) for key in ('heads', 'tails')}

for i, toss in enumerate(tosses, start=1):
    print(f'Result {i}: {toss}') 
    results[toss]['total'] += 1
    results[toss]['current'] += 1
    results[(results.keys() - [toss]).pop()]['current'] = 0
    results[toss]['best'] = max(results[toss]['best'], results[toss]['current'])

for k, v in results.items():
    print(f'The total amount of {k} is {v["total"]}')
    print(f'The best streak of {k} is {v["best"]}')
```